# Tensorflow predictions all come out true

Tags: tensorflow

In my tensorflow application, all the predictions are coming out True. I'm trying to adapt the MNIST example to my problem, but I'm worried that it's wrong to use that technique since its for multiple classes, and I have binary classification.

```
# In[1]:


import tensorflow as tf
import numpy


# In[2]:


X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3], "training-data")
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 2]), "W")
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]), "B") # number of neurons

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, 1]), "W1")
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), "B1") # number of neurons


# In[9]:


Y = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, W1) + b1)
Y1 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(Y, W2) + b2)
Y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], "labels") # labels

#cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(Y_ * tf.log(Y1)) # error function
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(Y1 - Y_))
is_correct = tf.equal(Y1, Y_)
# All the predictions are coming out True ?!?
accuracy = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(is_correct, tf.int32)) / tf.size(is_correct)

print("X", X)
print("Y", Y)
print("Y1", Y1)
print("Y_", Y_)
print("cross-entropy", cross_entropy)
print("is-correct", is_correct)
print("accuracy", accuracy)


# In[10]:


optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.005)
train_step = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)


# In[11]:


def load(filename):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename])
    key, value = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1).read(filename_queue)
    col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 = tf.decode_csv(records = value, record_defaults=[[1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0]])
    batch_size=100
    # A tensor for each column of the CSV
    load_time, is_east, is_west, is_europe, labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch([col1, col2, col3, col4, col5], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=batch_size*50, min_after_dequeue=batch_size)
    #features = tf.stack([load_time, is_east, is_west, is_europe], 1)
    features = tf.stack([is_east, is_west, is_europe], 1)
    return features, tf.reshape(labels, [-1, 1])


# In[12]:


features, labels = load("/Users/andrew.ehrlich/Desktop/labelled_clicks.csv")


# In[13]:


# Run!

test_features = numpy.loadtxt(open("/Users/andrew.ehrlich/Desktop/labelled_clicks_test.csv", "rb"), delimiter=",", skiprows=1, usecols = [1,2,3])
test_labels = numpy.loadtxt(open("/Users/andrew.ehrlich/Desktop/labelled_clicks_test.csv", "rb"), delimiter=",", skiprows=1, usecols = [4], ndmin = 2)

summ = tf.reduce_sum(test_labels)
size = tf.size(test_labels)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/Users/andrew.ehrlich/tf.log', sess.graph)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(1000):

        ran_features = sess.run(features)
        ran_labels = sess.run(labels)

        train_data = {X: ran_features, Y_: ran_labels}
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=train_data) # I guess this updates the tensors behind train_step (W and b)

        if (i % 100 == 0):
            train_acc, train_ent = sess.run([accuracy, cross_entropy], feed_dict=train_data)

            test_data = {X: test_features, Y_: test_labels}
            test_acc, test_ent = sess.run([accuracy, cross_entropy], feed_dict=test_data)

            size = sess.run(tf.size(ran_labels))
            print("batch size: %d [TRAIN - acc:%1.4f ent: %10.4f]    [TEST - acc:%1.4f ent: %10.4f]" % (size, train_acc, train_ent, test_acc, test_ent))


# In[ ]:
```

Output:

```
batch size: 100 [TRAIN - acc:0.4100 ent:    59.0000]    [TEST - acc:0.4787 ent:  9423.0000]
batch size: 100 [TRAIN - acc:0.5300 ent:    47.0000]    [TEST - acc:0.4787 ent:  9423.0000]
batch size: 100 [TRAIN - acc:0.5900 ent:    41.0000]    [TEST - acc:0.4787 ent:  9423.0000]
batch size: 100 [TRAIN - acc:0.4700 ent:    53.0000]    [TEST - acc:0.4787 ent:  9423.0000]
batch size: 100 [TRAIN - acc:0.5200 ent:    48.0000]    [TEST - acc:0.4787 ent:  9423.0000]
batch size: 100 [TRAIN - acc:0.6000 ent:    40.0000]    [TEST - acc:0.4787 ent:  9423.0000]
batch size: 100 [TRAIN - acc:0.5500 ent:    45.0000]    [TEST - acc:0.4787 ent:  9423.0000]
batch size: 100 [TRAIN - acc:0.6100 ent:    39.0000]    [TEST - acc:0.4787 ent:  9423.0000]
batch size: 100 [TRAIN - acc:0.4100 ent:    59.0000]    [TEST - acc:0.4787 ent:  9423.0000]
batch size: 100 [TRAIN - acc:0.5300 ent:    47.0000]    [TEST - acc:0.4787 ent:  9423.0000]
```

Accuracy doesn't change because the values of Y_ are always all True which results in a number that just shows the number of positive labels in the test set. Please let me know any feedback! I'm grateful!

Answer (score 1):

When your using `softmax` on your last layer and then calculating `cross_entropy`, combine together to a numerically stable `tf.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. Once you see that the loss is decreasing, but your accuracy is not good, then you can add complexity to the network by adding more layers.

Make the following changes:

```
Y1 = (tf.matmul(Y, W2) + b2)
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=Y1, labels=Y_))
```

Comment: I see in the doc: WARNING: This op expects unscaled logits, since it performs a softmax on logits internally for efficiency. Do not call this op with the output of softmax, as it will produce incorrect results. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits#autolink-21385

Comment: I changed the softmax layer to softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits. What should I use for the loss function? The old one is reporting NaN.

Answer (score 0):

You have a single output and I assume you expect it to be 0 and 1 for false and true. If that is the case, one of the problems is the softmax function. Softmax is good for multiple classes because one of its properties is that it makes the sum of all classes equal to 1 and it becomes easier to interpret the results as probability distributions. In your case, it just ends up setting your single output to 1 because of this property.

There are two basic ways to fix it. Either drop softmax on your output layer and maybe use a different loss function (mean square might work) or make your output layer return two values, keep softmax and interpret the resulting two numbers as a one-hot encoding where the actual values are a measure of confidence of the network.

Comment: I updated the last layer to be 2 instead of one, and I can see that Y contains the probabilities now. But the accuracy and entropy stay the same each batch. Using "Y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(X, W1) + b1)" and "loss = -tf.reduce_sum(Y_ * tf.log(Y))"